# Introduction to Real analysis

Tags: real-analysis

I have a somewhat difficult time understanding this line. Can someone please explain a little bit about this?
A ball of radius $\varepsilon$ around $x$ in $\mathbb{R}$ is a set deﬁned by: $$B_\varepsilon(x) = \{y \in \mathbb{R} : |x−y|< \varepsilon\}$$

Thanks for everyone

Comment: A ball are all the points that are at a distance less than a given distance from a given point. In $R$, the distance between two points $x,y$ is $|x-y|$. Therefore, the expression $|x-y|<\epsilon$ is saying the the distance between $x$ and $y$ is less than $\epsilon$. Hence $\{y\in R:|x-y|<epsilon\}$ can be read as: The set of all points $y$ such that the distance from it to the point $x$ is less than $\epsilon$.

Comment: When you start learning analysis, you may wonder why someone would define this. The idea behind this definition is to get a notion of 'nearby points'.

Answer (score 1):

... and therefore
$$
B_\epsilon(x) = (x-\epsilon,x+\epsilon),
$$
since $|x-y|<\epsilon$ is equivalent to $x-\epsilon<y<x+\epsilon$.

Answer (score -1):

in this case we talk about two distinct point (x,y) in R  |x−y|<ϵ say, ϵ always greater than distance of x & y. this can be easily understand in geometric representation